# How to mock a void method which acquires the lock in Zookeepr and we can also verify the locks

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, mockito, junit4

I have to create a unit testcases for a method which acquires the lock with zookeeper and data is processed with CompletableFuture are used

Below is the high level code :

```
import lombok.Data;
@Data
public class ConfigurationsIntegrationModel {
  public enum InteractionType {
    TEST,
    DEV;
  }
  private InteractionType interactionType;
  private String lockName;
}

import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

@Service("configurationsIntegrationService")
public interface ConfigurationsIntegrationService {
    public default List<ConfigurationsIntegrationModel> getRecords(ConfigurationsIntegrationModel.InteractionType integrationType) {
        return Arrays.asList(getDynamicIntegrationConfigurationMock(integrationType));
    }
    private static ConfigurationsIntegrationModel getDynamicIntegrationConfigurationMock(ConfigurationsIntegrationModel.InteractionType integrationType) {
        ConfigurationsIntegrationModel configurationsIntegration = new ConfigurationsIntegrationModel();
        configurationsIntegration.setLockName("Test_Lock");
        configurationsIntegration.setInteractionType(integrationType);
        return configurationsIntegration;
    }
}

import org.apache.curator.RetryPolicy;
import org.apache.curator.framework.CuratorFramework;
import org.apache.curator.framework.CuratorFrameworkFactory;
import org.apache.curator.framework.recipes.locks.InterProcessLock;
import org.apache.curator.framework.recipes.locks.InterProcessSemaphoreMutex;
import org.apache.curator.retry.RetryNTimes;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
public class DistributedLockProcessor {
    private CuratorFramework client;
    private String path;
    public DistributedLockProcessor(String host, String path) {
        RetryPolicy retryPolicy = new RetryNTimes(5, 90);
        client = CuratorFrameworkFactory.newClient(host, retryPolicy);
        client.start();
    }
    public InterProcessLock acquire(String lockName) throws Exception {
        InterProcessSemaphoreMutex sharedLock = new InterProcessSemaphoreMutex(client, path + "/" + lockName);
        if (!sharedLock.acquire(0, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) {
            return null;
        }
        return sharedLock;
    }
    public boolean release(InterProcessLock sharedLock) throws Exception {
        sharedLock.release();
        return true;
    }
}

import org.apache.curator.framework.recipes.locks.InterProcessLock;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.Executor;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.function.Consumer;
public class LockingExecutorProcessor<T> {
    private Executor executor = null;
    private DistributedLockProcessor distributedLock = null;
    public LockingExecutorProcessor(String host, String path, int executorCount) {
        executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(executorCount);
        distributedLock = new DistributedLockProcessor(host, path);
    }
    public void process(List<String> locks, List<T> items, Consumer<T> consumer) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
        final List<CompletableFuture<Void>> completableFutures = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < locks.size(); i++) {
            final int record = i;
            CompletableFuture<Void> future =
                    CompletableFuture.runAsync(
                            () -> {
                                InterProcessLock interProcessLock = null;
                                try {
                                    interProcessLock = distributedLock.acquire(locks.get(record));
                                } catch (Exception e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                                if (interProcessLock != null) {
                                    consumer.accept(items.get(record));
                                }
                            }, executor);
            completableFutures.add(future);
        }
        CompletableFuture<Void> completable = CompletableFuture.allOf(completableFutures.toArray(new CompletableFuture[completableFutures.size()]));
        completable.get();
    }
}

import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
@Service("messageService")
public interface MessageService {
    public default List<String> getMessagesList(ConfigurationsIntegrationModel.InteractionType integrationType) {
        return Arrays.asList("Message1", "Message2", "Message3","Message4");
    }
}

import com.google.common.util.concurrent.RateLimiter;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Scheduled;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
@Component("sampleJob")
public class SampleJob {
    @Autowired
    private LockingExecutorProcessor<ConfigurationsIntegrationModel> lockingExecutorProcessor;
    @Autowired
    private ConfigurationsIntegrationService configurationsIntegrationService;
    @Autowired
    private RateLimiter rateLimiter;
    @Autowired
    private MessageService messageService;

    private List<String> getLockNames(List<ConfigurationsIntegrationModel> integrationConfigurations) {
        List<String> lockNames = new ArrayList<>();
        for (ConfigurationsIntegrationModel integrationConfiguration : integrationConfigurations) {
            lockNames.add(integrationConfiguration.getLockName());
        }
        return lockNames;
    }
    @Scheduled(fixedRateString = "100")
    public void executeJob() throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
        List<ConfigurationsIntegrationModel> testRecords = configurationsIntegrationService.getRecords(ConfigurationsIntegrationModel.InteractionType.TEST);
        List<String> lockNames = getLockNames(testRecords);
        lockingExecutorProcessor.process(
                lockNames,
                testRecords,
                recordsConfig -> {
                    final List<CompletableFuture<Void>> completableFutures = new ArrayList<>();
                    List<String> msgList = messageService.getMessagesList(recordsConfig.getInteractionType());
                    for (String message : msgList) {
                        completableFutures.add(
                                CompletableFuture.runAsync(
                                        () -> {                                            
                                            System.out.println("Message is @@@@ "+ message);
                                        }, Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10)));
                    }
                });
    }
}
```

Below is the testcase which i tried so far :

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations;
import org.mockito.junit.MockitoJUnitRunner;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
    @RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class SampleJobTest {
    @InjectMocks
    private SampleJob sampleJob = new SampleJob();
    @Mock
    private ConfigurationsIntegrationService configurationsIntegrationService;
    @Mock
    private MessageService messageService;
    @Mock
    private LockingExecutorProcessor<ConfigurationsIntegrationModel> lockingExecutorProcessor;

    @Test
    public void testSampleJob() throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
        Mockito.doCallRealMethod().when(lockingExecutorProcessor).process(Mockito.any(), Mockito.any(), Mockito.any());
        Mockito.doCallRealMethod().when(configurationsIntegrationService).getRecords(Mockito.any());
        Mockito.doCallRealMethod().when(messageService).getMessagesList(Mockito.any());
        sampleJob.executeJob();
    }
}
```

When i debug the code then it breaks at the line CompletableFuture.runAsync of LockingExecutorProcessor and throws null pointer error; the reason is distributedLockProcessor object is null;

How can we mock it and how to connect to test zookeeper server instead of original to ensure locking is working fine

Comment: Please post the work you have tried so far at Junit side and elaborate what is not letting you to run your junit testcases. This will help others to help you out.

Comment: Updated the description

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is done. Now the testcases are working fine. I have used curator-test dependency and also used reflection to mock the private objects.